# How to Change logo Animated when scroll down? (Like Awwward website logo)

Tags: javascript, css, svg

> I'm familiar with CSS and javascript, but if the answer to this
>   question needs some changes to the SVG tag. Explain in more detail,
>   thank you

Q:

I want to create an animated SVG logo that responds to scroll down Like ***[This Link](https://www.awwwards.com/)***
(Note the scrolling behavior of the logo)

1. I know how to make an animated SVG but I want to know How associate logo behavior with scrolling.
2. How to do that with less js coding? (Or is it possible with pure CSS?)

Comment: Please show case what you have been able to achieve?

Comment: You can use the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event). Depending on what you need to achieve you nay need to use the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) Please edit your question and add your code like the svg you want to animate on scroll.

Comment: @TreeNguyen I want to achieve something like Awwwards.com header logo, I make SVG animation with adobe-animation but I think I need to do something in SVG tag to prepare this, I know how to use scroll-event but I don't want to just change logo image in two different scroll situation, I want to change logo animately and smoothly like awwward.com